# How to morphTarget of an .obj file (BufferGeometry)

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to morph the vertices of a loaded .obj file like in this example: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshDepthMaterial - when 'wireframe' and 'morphTargets' are activated in THREE.MeshDepthMaterial.

But I can't reach the desired effect. From the above example the  geometry can be morphed via `geometry.morphTargets.push( { name: 'target1', vertices: vertices } );` however it seems that `morphTargets` is not available for my loaded 3D object as it is a `BufferGeometry`.

Instead I tried to change independently each vertices point from `myMesh.child.child.geometry.attributes.position.array[i]`, it kind of works (the vertices of my mesh are moving) but not as good as the above example.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mchrbn/pen/YeRGOW) of what I could do.

How can I reach the desired effect on my loaded .obj file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding morph targets to `THREE.BufferGeometry` is a bit different than `THREE.Geometry`. Example:

```
// after loading the mesh:
var morphAttributes = mesh.geometry.morphAttributes;
morphAttributes.position = [];
mesh.material.morphTargets = true;

var position = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.clone();

for ( var j = 0, jl = position.count; j < jl; j ++ ) {

  position.setXYZ(
    j,
    position.getX( j ) * 2 * Math.random(),
    position.getY( j ) * 2 * Math.random(),
    position.getZ( j ) * 2 * Math.random()
  );

}

morphAttributes.position.push(position); // I forgot this earlier.
mesh.updateMorphTargets();
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ] = 0;

// later, in your render() loop:
mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ] += 0.001;
```

three.js r90

Comment: Thanks Don! It does not work yet - no errors but nothing is moving. Is `positionAttribute = mesh.geometry.attributes.position` ? I've updated my codepen with your code, in case.

Comment: Oops, I had some typos. And note that most of the code should be just done once after loading the mesh. Then in your render loop you do the last part, to transform to the morph target. Demo: https://codepen.io/donmccurdy/pen/mXaJgL?editors=0010

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for.